# Request page without .aspx

Tags: asp.net

How can you request the root default.aspx without specifying it in the url for your root application?

e.g.

http://localhost/MyApp/ instead of http://localhost/MyApp/Default.aspx

should be able to do both

I'm not sure if this is a setting in IIS 7.5 for the application or what.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default document for your website in your web.config in the `system.webserver` section - there's some documentation on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763179.aspx) on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the Default Document setting in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this http://www.isapirewrite.com/ , we can rewrite the URL using this. if it just default.aspx we can set that in IIS itself and IIS 7.x have more feature(SEO related).

Please check with for more details, if you want remove .aspx in every page http://forums.asp.net/p/1505464/3581724.aspx